# Four-momentum matrix dot product sigma matrix

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, metric-tensor, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

In the QFT book of Peskin and Schroeder, they introduce the notation:
\begin{align}
\sigma^{\mu}=(I,\sigma^{i})\\
\bar{\sigma^{\mu}}=(I,-\sigma^{i}).
\end{align}
On page 46 (Eq.(3.50)), They take the dot product with four-momentum
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{p \cdot \sigma}.
\end{equation}
How is the 'dot product' evaluated? is it pointwise multiplication:
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{p \cdot \sigma}=\sqrt{IE+p^{i}\sigma^{i}}?
\end{equation}
or, is it with Minkowskian signitaure:
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{p \cdot \sigma}=\sqrt{p_{\mu}\sigma^{\mu}}=\sqrt{IE-p^{i}\sigma^{i}}?
\end{equation}
The second option yields the right answer. So let's hope it's that one.

Answer (score 2):

The dot product on a Minkowski manifold is defined to have indefinite signature, so the second option is correct. P.S. uses $\eta_{\mu\nu} = \text{diag}(1, -1, -1, -1)$.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I wanted to know. The confusion arises because we are strictly speaking multiplying matrix entries. But apparently, the entries multiplication is pointwise with Minkowskian signature.